# What determines the physical appearance of a tangible amount of bacteria or viruses?

Tags: bacteriology, virology, coronavirus, experiment

As in the title, I was wondering how would feel an amount of one type of bacteria or virus, big enough to have a tangible size of the sample. What color, state (liquid, solid), textures, smell ecc. of the sample would be.

Ideally I would consider only the bacteria or virus, and none of their possible byproducts, and without any medium where they normally live in. Just the organisms in a tangible amount.

Therefore: why a set of bacteria will look like that? Why, for example, some are fluffly molds, others looks like a dough and so on. Is this representative of the physical structure of the bacteria?

Comment: Lab-grown E. coli is kind of a light-medium brown color, and smells like... E. coli. I don't know how to describe it. It's kind of squishy if you play with it, which I wouldn't recommend because you just used a lot of media to grow that much. I imagine it would get hard(er) if you dry it out, but I've never fully dried a pellet that big, just used it for protein purification.

Comment: It's going to ultimately depend on [just how much you have](https://what-if.xkcd.com/4/). I'm not really seeing the practical reasoning behind this question, though. Can you explain what is directly motivating your question, and perhaps narrow it down substantially?

Comment: It has absolutely nothing practical. It is more philosophical. I've read somewhere that the total amount of covid-19 in the world is estimated to be some hundreds of grams, and I wondered how that would look like if all gathered. Question is then extended to bacteria as well. In other words, is exactly in line with the "what-if" questions.

Comment: @BryanKrause I thought you were going to refer to [this xkcd](https://what-if.xkcd.com/80/), which is even more on-point.

Comment: @jakebeal Ah, had forgotten that one, nice!

Comment: @jakebeal there is always a relevant xkcd.

Comment: I was expecting a scientific answer. But I've got an equally valid xkcd link. Amazing! If that is true, if they look like that, I wonder if viruses are actually wet, or the "wettiness" is just how physically look like just the sheer amount of them. After all, water is not wet, if you take a bunch of molecule at a time. Actually, the concept of wet it would not even exist at that scale. Like a pool full of small balls: they look wet if you are big enough compared to the balls. Who knows if this applies here too. Should I move to stackexchange chemistry? :D

Comment: Is this really a question about a problem in biology at the standard of a site for professionals and serious students of biology? Or is it just idle curiosity about an unnatural situation to elicit a “fancy that!” response. Are you going to apply the information in any way? Do move the question to SE Chemistry — I imagine they will tell you what to do with it.

Comment: @David it is just idle curiosity. Moving to a place to know what to do with it, it would not help, as there is no practical reason behind. I am more active on electronics stackexchange, afaik over there humble curiosity for the sake of it is appreciated - when there is an effort shown. in this case, I did not know how to prove such effort, being illiterate in biology myself. for sure, I did not wanted to let anyone lose their time. my apologies if that was the case, although very unintended!

Comment: I am afraid that [Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), Biology and, one would imagine, any other SE have the same statement in the Help on questions not to ask "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." There is also the injunction "inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”" — describing the appearance and feel of something is not it. Try dried yeast in the supermarket or wet yeast in a baker's.

Comment: @David I understand now. I think the edit is more representative and more meaningful of the original question. If necessary, I will ask a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one answer to this question, any more than there is a single answer to the question of what color, texture, or size a mammal is.

To get a sense of some of the diversity out there, the American Society for Microbiology has a nice gallery of [bacterial colony morphology](https://www.asmscience.org/content/education/imagegallery/image.3114), showing that in most cases, you end up with basically variously colored and shaped blobs of snot-like substance. At a larger scale, some [microbial mats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microbial_mat) are formed of bacteria, and can form more fibrous mats bound together by extracellular substrate.

Comment: As mentioned in another comment, I wonder if when the sample looks "wet", is just an effect of the amount of the bacteria, or they are actually wet. Again, because the concept of wet would not exist if taking water molecules individually, maybe with bacteria is the same. I think all depends on the extracellular substrate here mentioned.

Comment: I'm not sure how meaningful it is to attempt to separate an organism from the context in which it normally lives in this manner. Consider [the fate of deep sea creatures brought to the surface](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/64318/what-happens-to-deep-sea-creatures-if-they-reach-the-surface).

Comment: Meaningful not quite. I thought more from a physical point of view. I began to work with e-ink displays which are using very small spheres. That made me think over different type of simple particles how result at a bigger scale, just with those particles. Then the curiosity was steered toward complex, not obvious structures, like bacteria, cells or viruses. To keep the same analogy, the thought was considering just the living creature, but in neutral atmosphere - therefore is a pure hypothetical situation, where a physics can answer, but physics are unaware of living creature dynamics.

Comment: Indeed the example of the fish makes sense, it cannot be considered out of the deep sea, neither the concept of (perceived) consistency of an object might look the same in such extreme pressure. Nice catch! But I think hypothetically bacteria have a theorized "consistency" at our pressures, so I thought it would be possible to imagine it (like in the xkcd comic) - hence why I asked biologists, not chemists.